# C# difference between Debug and Release

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Following code produces same output on 95% of machines, but on several there is difference. In Debug mode there is output:

```
Changing from New to Fin
OK
```

but in Release mode:

`Changing from New to Fin`

The `OK` line is missing. The project is targeted to .Net 4.0, build with VS 2015. You can download full sample [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3XycutP5o3hUnA5WFNveFU4U28).

Source code

```
using System;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Status current = Values.Status;
            if (current != Next())
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }

        static VO Values = new VO();
        private static Status Next()
        {
            Status res = Status.Fin;
            if (Values.Status == Status.New && Values.Cond)
                res = Status.Fin;
            else if (Values.Status == Status.Fin)
                res = Status.Fin;

            Log("Changing from {0} to {1}", Values.Status, res);
            Values.Status = res;
            return res;
        }
        public static void Log(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(format, args);
        }
    }

    public class VO
    {
        public Status Status;
        public bool Cond;
    }

    public enum Status { New, Fin }
}
```

This is in my opinion the minimal version to reproduce the error. After removing some of the conditions in Next(), inlining Log method, replacing Values.Cond with false causes the application behaves correctly.

**Edit**: It's not hardware related - operating system was extracted to Hyper-V and the problem persists.

Comment: Try putting the executables through an IL disassembler and see what differences there are in `Main`.

Comment: I get the same output for debug and release

Comment: Interestingly, in LinqPad, the first run produces two lines, the second (and all other consequent runs) produce just the first line without 'OK'. Im guessing it's the `static` that causes that.

Comment: @Joey you're right, I was thinking of `Debug.Writeline`

Comment: Are you rebuilding the release version? Are you running the newly built release code? One of those questions is false or there is a gigantic bug in the .NET Framework / MSBuild.

Comment: @rbm LinqPad will keep static values between builds. Make a change to the code (even just adding a blank line) and it will reset.

Comment: (yes, or Ctrl+Shift+F5 to reset)

Comment: @aquinas This sample is to reproduce error from much complicated application. This behavior I get on 2 machines out of 1000 on the rest it is working.

Comment: @JanZahradník You're saying if you take *this* sample application, run it on one machine, you see the correct output. Then you take the SAME bits (like you copy and paste from the machine where it worked), and run it on another machine you see different output?

Comment: Possibly the console output not being flushed before exiting the application under certain circumstance - try adding _"Console.Out.Flush();"_ as the final line of Main().

Comment: @PaulF: This snippet is the minimalistic version. In original version there was over 100 lines of code saving the object to database.

Comment: It would have to be a just-in-time compiler bug to behave this way.  They do happen, I'm not aware of any existing or previous bug that misbehaved on plain enums.  Unfortunately you target a very low .NET version and there have been a *lot* of bug fixes for v4.0.  Only reasonable thing you can do is to pay attention to the file version number for clrjit.dll.  Right-click the file and look at the Details tab.  Somewhat likely outcome that you find that the failing ones have an outdated unpatched version, but that's a guess.  Microsoft Support would normally help but 4.0 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment the problem was still reproducible with *clrjit.dll* version 4.6. After upgrading to 4.7 it disappears.